# Pandas: change multilevel column name for one particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
type      A                           B
kind      A1                          B1
name      alpha  aplpha1  alpha_dog   beta beta1 alpha_dog
timestamp
20180101  1      2        3           4     5    6
20180102  ...
20180103  ...
```

I want to change the `kind` of the `alpha_dog` columns, so I can have the following:

```
type      A                           B
kind      A1              google      B1         google
name      alpha  aplpha1  alpha_dog   beta beta1 alpha_dog
timestamp
20180101  1      2        3           4     5    6
20180102  ...
20180103  ...
```

I have looked at `df.rename/multiindex.rename` and none of them works for this cases and I found it really hard to do this operation, what's your opinion? Is there an easy option I can take?

Comment: This looks like inserting new labels (the value `google`) into the `kind` index level, without actually renaming any existing labels, right?

Comment: I would think not? For the first df the alpha_go has kind 'A1' and 'B1' respectively @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: The thing here is that for pandas if you sort index then you do not see repeated index values but they are actually there @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now: for every entry where `name='alpha_dog'`, you want to rename its `'kind'`-level label to `google`, right?

Comment: yep @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: Hmm... I'm not super familiar with MultiIndexes, so the only solution I can think of is going to be inefficient: transpose DataFrame, reset the MultiIndex into columns, replace text as needed using `.loc` with a boolean mask conditioned on if `name=='alpha_dog'`, set back into a MultiIndex, and transpose back :/

Comment: How about df.rename(columns={'sum':'new_name'}, level=1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of a `MultiIndex` are tuples, which are immutable, which is probably why it is so difficult to just change a single level value. Instead, create the new tuples, then assign the MultIndex again.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [(x, 'google', z) if z == 'alpha_dog' else (x,y,z) for x,y,z in df.columns], 
        names=df.columns.names)

type     A                      B                 
kind    A1           google    B1           google
name alpha alpha1 alpha_dog alpha alpha1 alpha_dog
0        1      1         1     1      1         1
1        1      1         1     1      1         1
2        1      1         1     1      1         1
```

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1]*6]*3)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    tuple((x,y,z) for x,y in zip(['A', 'B'], ['A1', 'B1']) for z in ['alpha', 'alpha1', 'alpha_dog']),
    names=['type', 'kind', 'name'])
```